# Laravel. Nested relations. Conditions from query outside

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have db tables are related to each other in this way:
*User - MainGoal - SubGoals - Budgets*.

User has one MainGoal

MainGoal has many SubGoals

SubGoal has many Budgets

Budget table has column user_id.

So my query builder looks like sth like this:

```
User::with('Maingoal.Subgoals.Budgets');
```

Eventually, I get Budgets for each Subgoal. BUT, I want to get budgets for exact users, for users from first query result in particular (*User::with*....).
Is it possible? What do you think?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: User has one maingoal, that has many subgoals that have one budget?

Comment: @TomaszRup, no, each subgoal has many budgets. Edited)

Comment: if your `Budgets` table has `user_id` in it, can't you define on User `hasMany('App\Budgets')`? And then just call `$user->budgets()`?

Comment: @TomaszRup, sure, I can. But Budgets table has sub_goal_id column as well. So, in this case, I don't need User-Budgets relation, I need another one.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to give condition in eager load, you can do this

```
User::with(['Maingoal.Subgoals.Budgets' => function($q) use ($id) {
    return $q->where('user_id', $id);
}])->get();
```

where $id is the id of that particular user

Comment: I don't know user's id. I will get it, when User::with(...)->get() be completed. But I want to retrieve it in closure.

Comment: I don't know how to achieve that easily using eager load, since you need a condition first before you can use the where clause. I think the only way that you can do right now is to pluck the id and do the for loop